# Clearing Screen in Swipl prolog in windows

Tags: windows, shell, command-line, prolog

When you are running command prompt in windows you can type the `clear` command to clear the screen. How do you do the same thing when you are running swipl prolog (by typing `swipl` in the command prompt) in windows?

Answer (score 23):

On unix terminals, there is the `library(tty)` resource and that has [`tty_clear/0`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=tty:tty_clear/0), but windows terminals do not support the terminal library.  However, they do support [ANSI Escape Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

Escape codes are character sequences starting with the `ESC` (escape) character, `ASCII 0x1B = 27`.  Most start with the control sequence introducer, which is the escape followed by a left bracker:  `ESC [`, known as the `CSI`.

So you can issue the code sequence for a screen clear, which is the ED (Erase Data) command, which takes the form:

```
CSI 2 J   -- which expands to: ESC [ 2 J
```

From SWI-Prolog this can be issued using the [`format/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=format/2) primitive.

```
format('~c~s', [0x1b, "[2J"]). % issue CSI 2 J
```

The ED 2 command, full terminal clear, on the MSDOS ANSI handling resets the cursor to top-left, but that is not necessarily the case on all terminals, so best to combine with the CUP (Cursor Position) command, which as a reset to home is simply: `CSI H`.

```
format('~c~s~c~s', [0x1b, "[H", 0x1b, "[2J"]). % issue CSI H CSI 2 J
```

---

**Update: Simplification**

Thanks to [@CapelliC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874024/capellic) for an alternate and clearer form, using the `\e` escape code for escape!

Plain clear screen:

```
cls :- write('\e[2J').
```

Or with home reset:

```
cls :- write('\e[H\e[2J').
```

Comment: Nice catch. I forgot about ANSI sequences. You can express ESC like \e, and thus store in SWI-Prolog configuration file the procedure: `cls :- write('\e[2J').` or `cls :- write('\e[H\e[2J').`

Comment: @CapelliC: Useful, I did not know it supported `\e`, a much cleaner refinement.

Comment: @CapelliC: `\e` is not ISO and is rejected by GNU and SICStus. Use `\33\ ` instead.